# How can i overload constructor with the same types?

Tags: c++

e.g let we have some struct that do some mathematics with 4 numbers and we want to do some particular things with particular values in two constructors, is it possible to overload constructor in way that we don't use any additional values(sort of mode switch)?

```
struct Coolness
{
    float a = float();
    float b = float();
    float c = float();
    float d = float();

    Coolness(float a, float b)
    {
        /* do stuff here*/ 
    }
```

Same types here but different values

```
    Coolness(float c, float d)
    {
        /* do other stuff here*/ 
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't. A new object is constructed with the different values. The way to go is add an if or switch inside your constructor if you want it to initialize stuff based on input.

Comment: How do you know which constructor you want to use? I would recommend an if statement in the constructor.

Comment: As far as I know, that is impossible. The compiler can't know which constructor you want to use if the arguments are the same.

Comment: Sounds like you have an X-Y problem. Rather than asking about a solution to a problem you're asking about solving the problems with a solution to a problem. What's the actual problem? There might be a simple solution to it that you have overlooked.

Comment: @RedKnite How would the if statement know which version to pick? Presumably the OP has something in mind but they're not telling. If the OP explains what's meant by 'sort of mode switch' there might be some solution.

Comment: @john I don't know how the if statement would tell because OP didn't say what they were trying to actually do. So yes there may be a solution, if it exists it is quite likely an if statement of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tag struct to differentiate. For example,

```
struct Coolness {
    struct Joe{};
    struct Fonz{};

    float a = float();
    float b = float();
    float c = float();
    float d = float();

    Coolness(Joe, float a_, float b_) : a{a_}, b{b_} {
        /* do stuff here*/ 
    }

    Coolness(Fonz, float c_, float d_) : c{c_}, d{d_)} {
        /* do other stuff here*/ 
    }

    static Coolness MakeFonz(float c, float d) {
         return Coolness{Fonz{}, c, d};
    }
};

int main() {
    Coolness x{Coolness::Joe{}, 7.0f, -3.333f};
    Coolness y{Coolness::Fonz{}, 1.0f, 2.0f};
    Coolness z = Coolness::MakeFonz(3.0f, 4.0f);
}
```

Update:  added a usage example, and added a static factory function to help illustrate how to use the technique.

Multiple static factory functions, without the tag structs, can be used to differentiate between different ways of constructing the object as well, rather than using any public constructors.

Comment: And then how can i call this constructors?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple overloads with the same signature.

An alternative is to create static methods that create the object for you. For instance, if you created your own `Complex` class you could have a static method to create a complex number from the real and imaginary parts, then you could have another static method to create an object passing the absolute value and the phase.

Comment: You can also keep the regular constructor for initializing from real and imaginary parts and create a "fromPolar" static method to create the complex from the absolute value and phase.